# "Translating" a POST File-Upload HTML to a curl command line

Tags: post, file-upload, curl, multipartform-data

I guess this should be pretty simple but I can't seem to get it working, plus googling is not getting me anywhere...
The HTML code is this:

```
<FORM ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data" METHOD="POST" ACTION="/Forms/Config_3">
<INPUT TYPE="FILE" NAME="FileUpload" SIZE="15" MAXLENGTH="15">
<INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" NAME="UPDATE_BUTTON" VALUE="Update" VALUE="Change">
```

How can I turn this into a curl command line?

Answer (score 14):

Something like:

```
curl -F "FileUpload=@filename.txt" http://DOMAINNAMEHERE.COM/Forms/Config_3
```

Comment: Problem solved... Nothing related to curl syntax as I initially thought, just a problem with the txt file format that was being silently rejected... Thanks...