# file upload via curl in bash

Tags: php, bash, file-upload, curl

How can I upload a file in a POST field on my website via curl directly rather using curl in php? In php you can do this with:

```
<?
$fileupload="image.jpg";
$c = curl_init("file");
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
array('Filedata'=>"@$fileupload",'folder'=>'/target/'));
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_exec($c);
curl_close($c);
?>
```

but how can this be done in a linux bash script with curl?

Comment: Possibly duplicate of [“Translating” a POST File-Upload HTML to a curl command line] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218954/translating-a-post-file-upload-html-to-a-curl-command-line)

Answer (score 1):

The CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS option sent as a hash array becomes a series of -F uses. Something similar to this:

```
curl -F Filedata=@image.jpg -F folder=/target/ [URL]
```